# Spring data jpa @Query - Cannot create an "AS" alias for a result map

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I map the result of the following `JPQL`-Query directly to a `SpecialCustomDto` object instead of the used `javax.persistency` entity object `MyEntity`. But I do not know, how to access the `COUNT(DISTINCT e.attributeB)`, which will be mapped to the `SpecialCustomDto`.

This is the query.

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

  @Query("SELECT new com.test.SpecialCustomDto(e.attributeA, COUNT(DISTINCT e.attributeB)) as specialCustomDto "
         + "FROM MyEntity e WHERE 5 = specialCustomDto.count GROUP BY e.attributeA")
  List<SpecialCustomDto> getSpecialCustomDtos(); 
}
```

As soon as I start the `spring-boot` application, Hibernate throws me following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: as near line 1, column...
```

I don't know how to access the aggregated `COUNT(DISTINCT e.attributeB)` element of the newly created `SpecialCustomDto`. Without the additional `WHERE`-clause, the mapping works as expected.

Comment: Check if it is allowed with `new com.test.SpecialCustomDto(e.attributeA, COUNT e.attributeB)`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried it and this was the result: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: COUNT near line 1,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the alias, move the condition to a HAVING-clause since it operates on an aggregate-value and just put the count-expression in there.

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

  @Query("SELECT new com.test.SpecialCustomDto(e.attributeA, COUNT(DISTINCT e.attributeB)) "
         + "FROM MyEntity e "
         + "GROUP BY e.attributeA "
         + "HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e.attributeB) = 5")
  List<SpecialCustomDto> getSpecialCustomDtos(); 
}
```

*Note: The `@Repository` is superfluous.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It worked as suggested. But in general: is it somehow possible to create an "AS" alias for the response mapping?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

Aggregate functions can be used as condition using `HAVING`. The same as in native SQL.

```
SELECT new com.test.SpecialCustomDto(e.attributeA, COUNT(e.attributeB))
FROM MyEntity e 
GROUP BY e.attributeA
HAVING COUNT(e.attributeB) = 5
```